# How to split string into an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

In Java, how do I split up a `string` into a `string[]`, separating each word?

I have a string as like this

```
"What is my name?"
```

And I want to show it in a TextView like this

> 1st word : What,
>
> 2nd word: is,
>
> 3rd word: my,
>
> 4th word: name.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking questions. Thanks

Comment: Read about the [String.split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string into array:

```
String x = "What is my name";
String[] splitted = x.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(splitted); i++) {
    System.out.println("Word " + (i+1) + ": " + splitted[i]);
}
```

You can change `System.out.println()` to your desired output method.

**Edit** *(as suggested in comment):* For safer code, change `Array.getLength(splitted)` to `splitted.length`.

```
String x = "What is my name";
String[] splitted = x.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Word " + (i+1) + ": " + splitted[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is `Array#getlength()`?

Comment: It gets the length of array `splitted`? Typo there though... `splitted.length` works too, it's just my personal preference when you don't know what type of array you will get, e.g. you have a method that takes `Object` as argument.

Comment: I just wondered where that class comes from, but as I can see, it's from the reflect package. Kind of dirty, since you don't get a proper compiler error when you made something wrong and pass the incorrect object. Using `.length` is much safer, since you don't rely on runtime exceptions, which might cause re-compilation and re-deployment of the whole code for an issue which could have been detected during compilation.

Comment: Yeah, your point is completely valid.